# Tweepyを使って、ある文字列を含んだツイートを一定間隔で習得し、そのツイートに含まれる文章をツイートする

Tags: python, twitter

現在、Tweepyでtwitterbotを作成しようとして、困っています。
ある文字列を含んだツイートを一定間隔で習得し、そのツイートに含まれてる文章をRTではなく自分でツイートするというプログラムを書きたいのですが、

```
got exception:
'SearchResults' object has no attribute 'text'
```

と出て、テキストが存在しないと出てしまいます。文章を取り出して、その内容をツイートすることはできないのでしょうか？
ソースコードは以下の通りです

```
# coding:UTF-8
import tweepy
import time

while True:


    CONSUMER_KEY = '***********'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = '******************************'
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
    ACCESS_TOKEN = '***********************'
    ACCESS_SECRET = '*******************************'
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_SECRET)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    search = api.search(q='#紙飛行機',lang='ja',count=10)
    try:
        api.update_status(search.text)
    except AttributeError as e:
        print("got exception:")
        print(e)

    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: ×習得→○取得の誤字でしょうか？

Comment: すみません。ご指摘通り、習得ではなく取得です

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html?highlight=search

> Help Methods API.search(q[, lang][, locale][, rpp][, page][,
>   since_id][, geocode][, show_user]) Returns tweets that match a
>   specified query.
>
> ***Return type:   list of SearchResult objects***

tweepyのAPI.searchのメソッドの戻り値はSearchResultオブジェクトのリストが返ってくるようです。
なのでこのようにすればよいと思います。

```
 search = api.search(q='#紙飛行機',lang='ja',count=10)
 for s in search:
     api.update_status(s.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

これで、ツイートとそれをツイートしたユーザー名もわかります

```
search = api.search(q='#あ',lang='ja',count=2)
for s in search:
    print(s.author._json['screen_name'])
    print(s.text)
```